# Resubmit form automatically

Tags: javascript, html, forms

We have a legacy web app at work that lets customer view their data on a graph.  They select options on a `<form>` and then submit.  A new page is displayed with instructions and FAQ's while a java applet displays the graph.  If I hit the F5 key in my browser, it resubmits the form and closes/re-opens the java applet which displays a graph with updated data.

Is there a way to duplicate that 'function' of resubmitting the graph in an automated fashion on a timer?  So the graph applet would redisplay every xx minutes without user intervention?

A simple meta refresh doesn't work as it doesn't resubmit the form.  I'm somewhat limited as to what I can modify.  The web app is completely generated by PL/SQL.

**EDIT**

For clarification: the `<form>` that the user filled in that produced the new page and java applet is not on the current page.  So there is no form to resubmit.  Hitting the F5 key will auto-resubmit the form that produced the current page.  I am looking for a programmatic way to do the same, if possible.

Comment: Can you include javascript as part of the page's output?

Comment: Perhaps you can't refresh the page and I belive you'll get that repost dialog if you manage. Can't you just reload the applet ?

Comment: You're right, I'd end up with that dialog box displaying which would defeat the purpose of not having user intervention.  Didn't think of that.  No, can't just reload the applet due to the way the back-end code supplies data to be graphed by the applet.  Have to update that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name your form `<form name="myform">` and I suppose you could

```
setInterval(myMethod, 300000);

function myMethod(){
    document.forms["myform"].submit();
}
```

Comment: See edit in original question.  I have a feeling I may have to put all the form elements that were on the original page into the 'new' page as hidden fields.  And then use your suggested code.

Comment: That would work. You can do them as hidden fields or put them in a hidden div.

Comment: That's what I'll do.  I'll accept this answer since I will be using it, and it's what "triggered" the idea to add the hidden form fields.  Thanks!